# InpressPages not upload images

Tags: impresspages

I trying to upload image, but it not displayed neither in admin-panel nor on page.

I see that file has been uploaded to /file/repository, but ImpressPages trying get this from /file/YYYY/MM/DD path.

How to fix uploading images?

PHP Version 5.3.3-7
GD Version  2.0

Answer (score 0):

Check PHP memory limit setting. 100 Mb of memory can handle about 3Mb JPG image.

Also try to upload smaller image. Like 100kb or so.

Comment: Memory limit is 512M.
Also, path is not created after upload file. I set 0777 rights to /file/ directory

Comment: Do you have friendly URLS enabled? Probably there is a bug if friendly URLs are off.

If friendly URLs are on. Ten inspect broken image and get URL of it. Open that url in new browser window and press browser's 'save as'. Open saved file with text editor. You will see actual error that prevented the file of being created.